# Progress Dialog doesn't disappear and seems to interrupt URL loading

Tags: java, android

I have a WebView that when it loads a site there will be a ProgressDialog showing. It works fine when you first open the app but when you click a link it just appears and doesn't go away until you click outside it. It also seems like the link the user clicked doesn't get loaded but when I remove the code for the ProgressDialog it works fine.

Thanks in advance!

```
package *package URL*;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment1, container, false);

    WebView webViewNews = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webViewNews);

    webViewNews.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewNews.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webViewNews.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    webViewNews.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    // this is necessary for "alert()" to work
    webViewNews.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    // load a page to get things started
    pd.show();

    webViewNews.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    return mainView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the ShouldOverrideUrlLoadning with onPageStarted and onPageFinished. I also decided to change the ProgressDialog with a Spinner for aesthetic reasons. Here are instructions on how I did it.

You add a spinner (also a wrapper for the spinner but not necessary) in the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#cc111111"
    android:id="@+id/pbWrapper">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:elevation="1000dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then add this BEFORE your onCreate

```
private ProgressBar mPbar = null;
private RelativeLayout mPbarWrap = null;
```

Then you need to find the spinner (and wrapper)

```
mPbar = (ProgressBar) mainView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mPbarWrap = (RelativeLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.pbWrapper);
```

Then finally show and hide the spinner (and wrapper) based on if there is a change in the WebView

```
webViewNews.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView mainView, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            mPbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPbarWrap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mPbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mPbarWrap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!